# Eclipse TreeMap debug view

Tags: eclipse, debugging, treemap

I am trying to see the items in the collection, but it seems like Eclipse just loops things over and over:
[image]

How can I see the individual items in the TreeMap collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a small button above the variables “Show Logical Structure”. Try it and it makes things easier. :-)